# How to query mongodb related subdocument?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

How can I write the query to get the results of the following fields:

```
 domain 
 url 
 description
```

Here are the current schemas . Please suggest if I need to redesign them.

```
const SchemaSerpQuery = new mongoose.Schema({
    query: { type: String, required: true },
    prospects: {
        url: { type: String },
        title: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
        siteId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Site" }, 
    },
});
```

Example of data I have in SerpQuery collection:

```
{
  _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f81,
  query: 'et',
  prospects: [
    {
      _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f82,
      url: 'http://geovanni.biz',
      title: 'Ut aspernatur at voluptatem inventore.',
      description: 'Qui porro perspiciatis architecto labore ab minima consequatur est. Repellat facere placeat animi laboriosam molestias aut rerum nulla. Voluptatem et numquam ab aperiam quam molestiae.',
      siteId: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7c
    },
    {
      _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f83,
      url: 'http://rhianna.biz',
      title: 'Id labore quia placeat qui.',
      description: 'Quas odit dolorem repudiandae aut. Ut aut ab. Cupiditate est porro aut. Totam illum aut iure rem cum maiores fuga.',
      siteId: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7d
    },
    {
      _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f84,
      url: 'https://moriah.biz',
      title: 'Nulla rerum saepe et aperiam.',
      description: 'Quia quisquam laboriosam exercitationem error placeat. Voluptas eum aut aspernatur architecto facilis aut. Debitis est perferendis et perspiciatis.',
      siteId: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7e
    },
    {
      _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f85,
      url: 'http://lavern.biz',
      title: 'Aut nam sint ut labore.',
      description: 'Molestiae ut ipsa. Et error magnam quo voluptatum. Est modi ullam ut in similique nam. Veniam non quia non nulla voluptatem omnis tempore dolorem.',
      siteId: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7f
    },
    {
      _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f86,
      url: 'http://jasen.net',
      title: 'Eum quis est sed odit.',
      description: 'Quia ut enim minus quibusdam ut deserunt qui perspiciatis est. Perferendis ratione commodi dolores praesentium est ipsa qui. Quo incidunt non saepe itaque. Cumque ab tempora qui exercitationem at in.',
      siteId: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f80
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

Schema for Site Collection

```
const SchemaSite = new mongoose.Schema({
    domain: { type: String, required: true },
    keywords: []
})
```

examples of documents in Site collection

```
[
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7c,
    domain: 'geovanni.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7e,
    domain: 'moriah.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7d,
    domain: 'rhianna.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7f,
    domain: 'lavern.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f80,
    domain: 'jasen.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f87,
    domain: 'mac.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f89,
    domain: 'reece.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f88,
    domain: 'lauren.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f8a,
    domain: 'shanel.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f8b,
    domain: 'akeem.com',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f94,
    domain: 'ladarius.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f92,
    domain: 'kaitlyn.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f93,
    domain: 'carmine.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f95,
    domain: 'kurtis.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f96,
    domain: 'percy.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9f,
    domain: 'america.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9d,
    domain: 'margaretta.name',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9e,
    domain: 'aileen.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa0,
    domain: 'charles.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa1,
    domain: 'ladarius.name',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa9,
    domain: 'krystel.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa8,
    domain: 'markus.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1faa,
    domain: 'ford.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fab,
    domain: 'breanna.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fac,
    domain: 'jaylon.info',
    __v: 0
  }
]
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
[
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7c,
    domain: 'geovanni.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7e,
    domain: 'moriah.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7d,
    domain: 'rhianna.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f7f,
    domain: 'lavern.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f80,
    domain: 'jasen.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f87,
    domain: 'mac.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f89,
    domain: 'reece.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f88,
    domain: 'lauren.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f8a,
    domain: 'shanel.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f8b,
    domain: 'akeem.com',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f94,
    domain: 'ladarius.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f92,
    domain: 'kaitlyn.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f93,
    domain: 'carmine.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f95,
    domain: 'kurtis.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f96,
    domain: 'percy.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9f,
    domain: 'america.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9d,
    domain: 'margaretta.name',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1f9e,
    domain: 'aileen.net',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa0,
    domain: 'charles.biz',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa1,
    domain: 'ladarius.name',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa9,
    domain: 'krystel.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fa8,
    domain: 'markus.info',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1faa,
    domain: 'ford.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fab,
    domain: 'breanna.org',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    keywords: [],
    _id: 5fcca13302f9f65537ce1fac,
    domain: 'jaylon.info',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Is it possible to populate an embedded document of a collection?

Comment: Use lookup function of mongodb and try to get results, Refer to this official document of MongoDB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/